# How to remove the first instance of something in a file with awk?

Tags: awk

If I have a file with multiple lines with

```
...
  end
...
  end
...
  end
...
```

How could I remove only the first instance?

So far I have tried

```
 awk 'BEGIN {found=false} /  end/ { d; found=true} else {print}'

 awk 'BEGIN {found=false} {/  end/ {found=true} else {print}}'
```

as a start/guess but it is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a variable to track the first matched:

```
awk -v first=1 'first && /  end/ {first=0;next};1' <file
```